# Bookshelf Arrangement Dilemma

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I bought a new bookshelf yesterday, but now I have a dilemma.

I've got all these books and I'm trying to figure out the most aesthetically pleasing and, of course, *efficient* arrangement, but I need help deciding.

Here are the three configurations I've tried so far:

[image]  [image] 
 [image]

- Do you think the first one is better than the second?
- Do you think the second one is worse than the third?
- Do you think the first one is better than the third?
- Do you think the third one is worse than the first?
- Do you think the second one is better than the third?
- Do you think the third one is better than the first?

Most importantly, I ask this:

### **Is there something seriously wrong with me?**

Comment: Much the same thing (if Deusovi's answer is right, which it surely is) may be wrong with me, because I am troubled by the fact that these are _clearly not actually different arrangements of the same set of books_.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I would have thought that the lighting would bother some people. (The books seem to be lit decidedly from the left, but the shelves have shadows that infer an overhead light source.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems your books are subtly hinting at what's "wrong" with you:

> The blue and red books in each layout form a letter. These letters spell out **OCD**, which must be the problem you're facing.

Comment: Just how on earth did I not notice that? It looks so obvious, now that I see it! I will be sure to upvote when my daily voting limit is over :D